# How do I grab the word in a character column after two consecutive word matches in R?

Tags: r, loops, nested-loops

I have a data frame 'key_words' with vectors of pairs of words

```
key_words <- data.frame( c1 = ('word1','word2'), c2 = ('word3, word4'), c3 = ('word5','word6'))
```

I would like to search for these pairs of key words in a character column 'text' in another data frame 'x' where each row can be a few sentences long. I want to grab the word following two consecutive matches of a column in the key_words data frame and insert that value into a table at the same index of where the match was found. For example, if 'word1' and 'word2' are found one after the other in text[1] then I want to grab the word that comes after in text[1] and insert it into table[1].

I have tried splitting each row in 'text' into a list, separating by a single space so that each word has its own index in each row. I have the following idea which seems very inefficient and I'm running into problems where the character value temp_list[k] is of length 0.

```
x <- x %>% mutate(text = strsplit(text, " "))  
for (i in 1:ncol(key_words)) {
    word1 <- key_words[i, 1]
    word2 <- key_words[i, 2]
    for (j in 1:length(x$text)) {
      temp_list <- as.list(unlist(x$text[[j]]))
      for (k in 1:length(temp_list))
        if (word1 == temp_list[k]) {
          if (word2 == temp_list[k + 1]) {
            table$word_found[j] <- temp_list[k + 2]
          }
        }
    }
```

Is there a better way to do this or can I search through the text column for 'word1 word2' and grab the next word which can be any length? I'm new to R and coding in general, but I know I should be avoiding nested loops like this. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you create a small function like this one, that returns the word following the occurrence of the pair 'w1 w2'

```
get_word_after_pair <- function(text,w1,w2) {
  stringr::str_extract(text, paste0("(?<=\\b", w1, "\\s", w2, "\\b\\s)\\w*(?=\\b)"))
}
```

and then you can do this

```
data.frame(
  lapply(key_words, function(x) get_word_after_pair(texttable$text,x[1],x[2]))
)
```

### Input:

(`keywords` is a list of word pairs, `texttable` is a frame with a column `text`)

```
key_words <- list( pair1 = c('has','important'), pair2 = c('sentence','has'), pair3 = c('third','sentence'))

texttable = data.frame(text=c("this sentence has important words that we must find",
                              "this second sentence has important words to find",
                              "this is the third sentence and it also has important words within")
)
```

### Output:

```
  pair1     pair2 pair3
1 words important  <NA>
2 words important  <NA>
3 words      <NA>   and
```